# Boolean as on/off switch for a method

Tags: objective-c

i have a singleton with a boolean and im trying in one of my VC to make a method that will be called whenever this boolean change value.

for example it will be like:

```
-(void)onOff:(bool)flag {

    if (flag){}
    else {}
}
```

its a global bool (not declared in a specific viewcontroller)

how can i create an observer/flaged method of the global bool?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: edited - im trying to find a way to make some observer for a method that will call the method whenever the global bool change, how can i make it?

Comment: You are thinking about this backwards. If you want to know when a value is changed, make it private and provide a public accessor that must be called in order to change that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Approach can be - You can use **Notifications** for this

Add **Observer** in your view controller where Updation needs to be done

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(booleanValueChanged:) 
        name:@"BOOLEAN_NOTIFICATION"
        object:nil];

- (void) booleanValueChanged:(NSNotification *) notification
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    BOOL flag = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"booleanValue"] boolValue];
}
```

Now wherever you are changing the value of that bool, Use the following code:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:flag] forKey:@"booleanValue"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"BOOLEAN_NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```